# Symfony/composer showing Deprecated errors with php8.2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to get the latest version of mPDF for my recently upgraded (centos) dev php environment (now on php 8.2.10) but I am getting the following Symfony error:

```
$ composer require mpdf/mpdf

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony3/Component/Console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 104
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema5/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Process\Process::getIterator($flags = 0) should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony3/Component/Process/Process.php:567
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:286
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:286
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:286
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:799
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:804
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
```

Where do I go with this?

(PS. I'm no sysadmin expert here...I dev well but I don't admin well. Any assistance would be grateful)

**Edit #1 - added version information:**

```
$ composer --version

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony3/Component/Console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 104
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema5/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Process\Process::getIterator($flags = 0) should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony3/Component/Process/Process.php:567
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:286
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:286
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:286
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:799
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:804
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]?
Composer 2.1.3 2021-06-09 16:31:20
```

Comment: Which version of Composer do you use? Also, which error do you refer to? The output you've shared doesn't contain a single error message

Comment: Hi Nico - I've updated the question to include version info

Comment: Well, Composer v2.1.3 is pretty outdated, as you see in the date information. Update it to any more current version, which also supports PHP 8.2

Comment: Any suggestions how...  `composer self-update` returns (as well as all the deprecation alerts), "`Command "self-update" is not defined.`"

Comment: I have no clue how you installed it in the first place, but there are already other questions on StackOverflow about that exact error

Comment: Ok - I think I've updated composer:
1) `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
2) `php composer-setup.php`
3) `mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`
4) `composer` ... gives Composer 2.6.3 now

This has now allowed me to run `composer require mpdf/mpdf` with no errors. 

Thanks Nico for the nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - with help from a nudge from Nico, I've updated composer and then updated mPDF

```
$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
$ php composer-setup.php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
$ composer --version

$ composer require mpdf/mpdf
```